# Set variables in /etc/login.defs using script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm looking to write a script that will make sure my /etc/login.defs file hasn't been tampered with. If a setting has been changed, I want this script to fix it. 
I've been able to write the section of the script that "pulls" the variables out of the file and checks them against a list I have in my script, but I don't know how to set the variables if they have, in fact, been changed. Is there any way to set specific variables in /etc/login.defs using a script?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for http://cfengine.com/

Comment: @sjsam Already fixed, but thanks for the report.

Comment: Why aren't you just reverting the entire file instead of trying to change a variable at a time?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking to ... make sure my ... file hasn't been tampered with

```
chattr +i filename
```

is the best option if the `filename` is a read-only and is not supposed to change. You can escape writing a script then. :-)

Here, the `i` option is for `immutable`. Fore more info, check the man page for [[ chattr ]](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr).